# CSS IE Filter and background image?

Tags: css

Can you use the CSS Filter attribute for IE gradients AND implement a background image?

```
/*filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#2c8bcf', endColorstr='#0068b3');*/
```

Comment: There's something so wrong about having to use proprietary code for the one browser that doesn't even bother to follow standards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know the background has to be "transparent" or none for the gradient filter to work..

perhaps you could wrap the gradient `div` with another `div` and put the background image on the outer one?

**Wait!** it does appear to work, glad I checked..

#### [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/4YUrM/) (IE only)

sorry about that I really thought it didn't work with a background, but couldn't find a reliable source  - anyway in that fiddle above I changed the gradient to go from transparent to black

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced that it can be done.  It appears that in the jsfiddle above, the hex values have an extra 2 "0"s in them.  if you set the values to actual hex chars, the example does not work.  perhaps the background will show through if the gradient is going from transparent to a color only